# How can use the 'coding' header of a python source file to read its contents properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

Python source files often come with a `coding` header similar to the following

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

How can I this line to properly parse the contents of such a file? Is there a better way than manually opening the file in binary mode, reading one line, and checking if it contains the header? Is there a library that does this?

---

Background: this comes in the context of fixing [this bug](https://github.com/alecthomas/importmagic/issues/13), which crashes elpy when used in conjunction with python3 and importmagic. The code that I'm trying to fix uses

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    success = subtree.index_source(filename, fd.read())
```

and crashes on non-utf-8 files. Ideally I would like to keep changes to a minimum.

Comment: "better way" is such an extremely relative thing that I'm tempted to ignore your question. What is bad about the way you're currently doing it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - considering that python supports some source encoding schemes, it is reasonable to assume that there is an already existing python library to read such files. There are several formats, 8 vs. 16 bit encodings, BOMs and etc..., its not an obvious thing to do on your own.

Comment: ah, but there's a PEP that already describes how this should be handled

Comment: @tdelaney: I've added an answer based on your inspiration; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is [`tokenize.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.detect_encoding) that does exactly that: it opens a Python source file using the character encoding specified in the `coding` header ([encoding declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)).

You could [decode on-the-fly remote Python files too](https://gist.github.com/zed/dbdccd6d996b974e20cd).